# Copy from HDD to USB 3.0 is really slow with Thunar, cp, and rsync

Tags: backup, usb-drive

I was trying to copy files with `rsync` from my laptop to a USB 3.0 external hard drive, but it was going really slow. Just for reference, this is the command I was using:

```
rsync -a src/ dest/ --info=progress2
```

And by slow, I mean as slow as 5 MB/s at times. I'd say most of the time it stayed between 15 and 20 MB/s.

I am pretty confident the issue is not with `rsync`, neither with the fact that I'm copying multiple files. Copying a single large file (9 GB) is also slow.

I know I have a functional USB 3.0 port because Windows can copy at 120 MB/s.

Linux *seems* to understand this is a USB 3.0 device. Here's what `lshw` have to say about my USB port and exernal HD:

```
*-usbhost:1
     product: xHCI Host Controller
     vendor: Linux 6.1.0-13-amd64 xhci-hcd
     physical id: 1
     bus info: usb@2
     logical name: usb2
     version: 6.01
     capabilities: usb-3.10
     configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=10000Mbit/s
   *-usb
        description: Mass storage device
        product: EXTERNAL_USB
        vendor: TOSHIBA
        physical id: 2
        bus info: usb@2:2
        logical name: scsi2
        version: 0.00
        capabilities: usb-3.00 scsi emulated
        configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=896mA speed=5000Mbit/s
      *-disk
           description: SCSI Disk
           product: EXTERNAL_USB
           vendor: TOSHIBA
           physical id: 0.0.0
           bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
           logical name: /dev/sdb
           version: 0
           size: 931GiB (1TB)
           capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
           configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=3083634d
```

And this is the output of `lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

I don't understand. If I am reading these correctly, I should be copying at over 100 MB/s. But it seems very far from that. What is wrong?

(I appreciate all the suggestions in the comments, but I'm not looking for a backup tool. I cannot copy the entire partitions because I don't have enough external HDs to match the partitions in my laptop. Besides, I am looking for a solution that will just make my USB 3.0 work properly)

Comment: Try [CloneZilla LiveCD/USB](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) for this.  I'm not recommending it, but this is pretty much the de facto backup tool for Linux'es

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. But your reference says "you must first prepare a DRBL server AND the machine to be deployed must boot from a network". I'm just trying to make a backup of my personal data.

Comment: Clonezilla is a recomended for making a disk image copy. You can restore the whole disk, but you cannot restore individual files. My Clonezilla runs at approx 10GB/minute from an internal SATA "disk" via a USB 3.0 to an external 7200 HD.

Comment: I wish I could but I can't use that either. I want to copy files from my HDD and my SD. Both to the same partition in an external HD. I can't copy the entire partitions. They are larger than the external HD.

Comment: What port are you using? It looks like only one port is faster? `Bus 02.Port 1:`

Comment: @giusti You do not need a DRBL server to run CloneZilla, which is what Jeremy and I recommended.  I'll look at their LivePage again , but I believe the DRBL server is only needed when doing a local to network backup, or a backup deployment/restore over network.  In your case, you'd be doing a local to local backup.  Are you currently booted to/using the partition you're copying files from?

Comment: Continued: Quoting - " Clonezilla SE (Server Edition)...  In order to use it, you must first prepare a DRBL server AND the machine to be deployed must boot from a network (e.g. PXE/iPXE)."  That quote is not referring to the Debian based Live Distribution linked in the next paragraph. Quoting again: "To address these limitations, we have combined Debian Live with Clonezilla as "Clonezilla Live," a software that can be used to easily image and clone individual machines. The primary benefit of Clonezilla Live is that it eliminates the need to set up a DRBL server ahead of time.."

Comment: @oldfred That's the one I'm using. Both `lshw` and `lsusb` confirm the mass storage device is plugged into the one  with 10G/5G speed.

Comment: @eyoung100 I will look into it. Thank you. But I still would like to copy with `rsync`. It should work. At least with one large file. In the future I will want to only copy the files that have been modified to this backup.

Answer (score 1):

Test the USB HDD directly with `dd` and the `status=progress oflag=direct` to see if it is something with the USB / drive. I.E. `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4M status=progress oflag=direct of=/dev/sdX` (Note: urandom might be a bottleneck itself, you can try reading an nvme or something if you have one.)
If you're getting good speeds directly to the drive then it may be filesystem format related.

Assuming you're using the NTFS-3g module I've had similar performance issues with it. You could try formatting a drive to ext4/btrfs and see if you get good performance with 1st party formats. If you need the data accessible in Windows you could try exFAT or FAT32 (has 4GB file limit). You can use `GParted` to help with formatting on Linux if you don't know/want to do it in the CLI.

If the direct test with `dd` is slow then you can try messing with the USB / xHCI settings in the BIOS/Firmware. xHCI handoff is a feature some motherboards have and I've personally had to turn it off on a Linux machine once to prevent it from randomly disconnecting USB devices. There could be some tweaking required there.

Comment: I could not do the exact procedure you suggested because I would have to undo the backup, but I did copy a 32GB file with random data using `dd`. It averaged 80 MB/s. Still a bit slower than what USB 3.0 should do, but significantly faster than what I was getting.

Comment: Weird thing... my backup HD has two partitions. One is EXt4 and one is NTFS. I was `rsync`ing from my laptop EXT4 to my backup EXT4...

Comment: I'll be damned... Copying with `cp` from the EXT4 to the NTFS partition works just fine. I ran `cp /tmp/random /media/ntfspartition && sync` and it took 4min18s to copy a 32 GB file (about 127 MB/s).